# Issue with setting a correct regular expression in C using regex

Tags: c, regex

I'd like to match all strings that begin with a set of characters `a-z`, then exactly one `:` and another set of characters `a-z` right after that.

So as an example, the string `"an:example"` would be a correct match.

And another example, `"another:ex:ample"` needs to be a mismatch.

I have tried to set it up like that but it matches everything, even if i take bad string as input :(

So my regular expression is `"[a-z]:[a-z]"` but it evaluates the string `"1an:example"` as a *Match* :/

How can I do this correctly?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex.h>

int main() {
   regex_t regex;
   int retis;
   char* str = "1an:example";
   
   retis = regcomp(&regex, "[a-z]:[a-z]", 0);
   retis = regexec(&regex, str, 0, NULL, 0);
   
   if(!retis) {
      puts("Match");
   }
   else if(retis == REG_NOMATCH) {
      puts("No match");
   }
   
   regfree(&regex);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you need beginning- and end-of-string markers: `^[a-z]:[a-z]$`?

Comment: @MOehm I tried this but it doesn't work either and I have no clue why :(

I used as input string: "an:example" and I got a mismatch with regular expression: "^[a-z]:[a-z]$"

Comment: `regexec` searches, rather than matches.

Comment: Okay, you got your answer now. (Didn't see that the repetition suffix `+` was mssing. Sorry about that.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need

```c
retis = regcomp(&regex, "^[a-z]+:[a-z]+$", REG_EXTENDED);
```

See the [C online demo](https://ideone.com/IGR4YX).

That is:

- `^` (start of string) and `$` (end of string) are [anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) that require the regex to match the whole string
- `[a-z]+` matches *one or more* lowercase letters
- `REG_EXTENDED` allows extended regex syntax, e.g. in `regex.h` it is required to enable the `$` anchor.

Comment: Thank you! This makes it all work correctly now and now I can go and make some other regular expressions with it. And thanks to everyone who posted here too! :)